# Pronic / Bi Pronic numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have searched for open problems about pronic numbers but nothing turned up. Is there an open or related problem about pronic numbers that anyone knows of?

Comment: Can you add some relevant links? Like [pronic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronic_number) and maybe talk a little more about what is interesting about this set of numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should let readers know what the pronic numbers are, as it is not a term frequently used. A pronic number is a number of the form $n(n+1).$ You can find them in Sloan's database as sequence [A002378](https://oeis.org/A002378). Now, [Oppermann's Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oppermann%27s_conjecture) might interest you. Following the Wikipedia entry - *Is every pair of a square number and a **pronic number** (both greater than one) separated by at least one prime*?

---

Remark: There is also this entry at MathWorld on [pronic numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PronicNumber.html); which details the curious history of the word "pronic."