# Is there a prime between any two consecutive pronic numbers?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

**Definition:**

A *pronic number* $m$ is an integer number that can be written as $n(n+1)$, for some integer $n$.

**Conjecture:**

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Then there is a prime $p$ such that $n(n+1) \le p \le (n+1)(n+2)$. Recall that the prime counting function $\pi(x)$, for some real number $x$, is the number of prime numbers less than or equal to $x$. Then, equivalently, we can write the conjecture as follows:
$$\pi((n+1)(n+2)) - \pi(n(n+1)) > 0$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

**Attempt:**

I worked this out until the number $n=11$ and it still works. I also tried doing a proof for this, but I only proved that since the gap between consecutive pronic numbers increases linearly (i.e., increases $2(n+1)$, for any positive integer $n$), there will be more primes in the range given above.

**Question:**

Is this true? Or is there a counterexample?

Comment: [Legendre's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture) seems related to this question (or at least in the same spirit).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pronic / Bi Pronic numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3414007/pronic-bi-pronic-numbers) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24n(n%2B1)%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24(n%2B1)(n%2B2%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Apronic%2C%20OR%20content%3Aprimes&p=1).

Comment: Wouldn't Bernards postulate come into play. $(n+1)(n+2) = n(n+1) + 2(n+1)$ and... oh I guess not ... but seems related.

Comment: The best proven upper bound for prime gaps is worse than $\sqrt{p}$ , so not sufficient for a proof. But since the upper bound is probably much smaller (maybe we even have $g(p)<\ln^2(p)$) , we only need check this conjecture upto , say , $n=10^4$ to have a good evidence that it is true. A rigorous proof as so often when it comes to concrete primes should be out of reach.

Comment: For $1\le n\le 10^7$ , there is always a prime $p$ with $n(n+1)<p<(n+1)(n+2)$

Answer (score -1):

If we assume Legendre's conjecture, then there would always be a prime between two consecutive proning numbers (i.e., Legendre's conjecture considers smaller intervals than $(n+1)(n+2)-n(n+1)$, but unfortunately $[n^2, (n+1)^2] \not\subseteq [n(n+1),(n+1)(n+2)]$).

In details, Legendre's conjectures states that there is (at least) one prime between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$ for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.
Now, we note that $n(n+1) \leq p \leq (n+1)(n+2) \Rightarrow n^2+n \leq p \leq n^2+3n+2$. Consequently, $n^2+3n+2 - (n^2+n)= 2(n+1)$ is always greater that $(n+1)^2-n^2$, since $n^2+3n+2 - (n^2+n) > (n+1)^2-n^2$ implies $2(n+1) > 2n+1$, which holds for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

This is not a proof, but a good argument to let us speculate that Legendre's conjecture would represent a sufficient, but not a necessary, condition for the pronic numbers conjecture.